# change stroke-dashoffset base on data attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 circles with an svg i'm trying to change the stroke-dashoffset base on the data attribute data-num to have different size of circle that match the value of data-num

I'm trying the code below but the value of stroke-dashoffset donesn't change

How can i change the value of stoke-dashoffset to have the value of data-num and keep the animation for the circle?

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const svgEl = document.querySelectorAll('svg circle');
const counters = Array(numbers.length);
const intervals = Array(counters.length);
counters.fill(0);

numbers.forEach((number, index) => {
    intervals[index] = setInterval(() => {
        if(counters[index] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)){
            clearInterval(counters[index]);
        }else{
            counters[index] += 1;
            number.innerHTML = counters[index] + "%";
            svgEl[index].style.strokeDashoffset = 472 - 472 * parseInt(number.dataset.num / 100);
        }
    }, 20)
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.skill-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.skill-container .skill {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.skill-container .skill .outer {
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0 0 0 /.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255 255 255 / .7);
}

.skill-container .skill .outer .inner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0 0 0/ .2),
        inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255 255 255 /.7),
        -.5px -.5px 0px rgba(255 255 255 / 1),
        .5px .5px 0px rgba(0 0 0 /.15),
        0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0 0 0 / 0.05);
}

.skill-container .skill .outer .inner .number {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(1) .outer .inner .number {
    color: #f75023;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(2) .outer .inner .number {
    color: #4fa0ff;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(3) .outer .inner .number {
    color: #7811f7;
}

circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #f75023;
    stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke-dasharray: 472;
    stroke-dashoffset:472;
    animation: anim linear 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 70;
    }
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(1) circle {
    stroke: #f75023;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(2) circle {
    stroke: #4fa0ff;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(3) circle {
    stroke: #7811f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-container">
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="number" data-num="90">
                        90%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="number" data-num="50">
                        80%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="number" data-num="70">
                        85%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the second 472 to 440

and

I used parseFlot not Int and the problem is solved

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const svgEl = document.querySelectorAll('svg circle');
const counters = Array(numbers.length);
const intervals = Array(counters.length);
counters.fill(0);

numbers.forEach((number, index) => {
    intervals[index] = setInterval(() => {
        if(counters[index] === parseInt(number.dataset.num)){
            clearInterval(counters[index]);
        }else{
            counters[index] += 1;
            number.innerHTML = counters[index] + "%";
            svgEl[index].style.strokeDashoffset = Math.floor(472 - 440 * parseFloat(number.dataset.num / 100));
        }
    }, 20);
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.skill-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.skill-container .skill {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.skill-container .skill .outer {
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 10px -1px rgba(0 0 0 /.15), -6px -6px 10px -1px rgba(255 255 255 / .7);
}

.skill-container .skill .outer .inner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 6px -1px rgba(0 0 0/ .2),
        inset -4px -4px 6px -1px rgba(255 255 255 /.7),
        -.5px -.5px 0px rgba(255 255 255 / 1),
        .5px .5px 0px rgba(0 0 0 /.15),
        0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0 0 0 / 0.05);
}

.skill-container .skill .outer .inner .number {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(1) .outer .inner .number {
    color: #f75023;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(2) .outer .inner .number {
    color: #4fa0ff;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(3) .outer .inner .number {
    color: #7811f7;
}

circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #f75023;
    stroke-width: 20px;
    stroke-dasharray: 472;
    stroke-dashoffset:472;
    transition: 2s linear;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(1) circle {
    stroke: #f75023;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(2) circle {
    stroke: #4fa0ff;
}

.skill-container .skill:nth-child(3) circle {
    stroke: #7811f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-container">
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="number" data-num="90">
                        90%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="number" data-num="50">
                        80%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="number" data-num="70">
                        85%
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="160px" height="160px">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
                        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e91e63" />
                        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#673ab7" />
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```